# How can I use a Windows 8 computer with no dvd drive to make a Windows 8 .iso file?

Tags: windows, windows-8, iso-image

I found out how to make a CustomRefresh.wim file and I found out how to make a recovery USB (that includes the folders boot, efi and sources) but I can't find how to make a .iso file that I can use in virtual box. All the tutorials I can find on youtube are about how to make an .iso if you have a cd/dvd drive and my computer didn't come with one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool in the windows 8.1 automated deployment kit called oscdimg.exe, it is a command line interface to create an .iso file from a directory.

[image]

Link to ADK.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652

Comment: Which directory should I use? Would it work to just make C: an iso file? Or make E: an Iso file? (that's my recovery flash drive)

Comment: the directory that includes the boot, efi, sources folders and your custom .wim file.